# Random value. How to sum values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, random, spreadsheet

This is a risk analysis app.
I'm not very good at sheets and looking for advice

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yFq7XCypJK77CBZc3x9tlEsW63mFy21nuO3I9kzGHaQ/edit?usp=drivesdk

Can anyone advise how to adjust the account balance to account for each time pnL unrealized updates?  I'd like it to accumulate all the numbers that are Generated each time the page refreshes?

For example if page refreshes 3 times and the values of purple pnL unrealized happened to be
-200,  500, 250

Account balance would update each time and would finally read

Account balance = $50,550.

I'm using the random number generator =RANDBETWEEN(-C6,C6)
For the pnL unrealized.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yFq7XCypJK77CBZc3x9tlEsW63mFy21nuO3I9kzGHaQ/edit?usp=drivesdk

Not great at these formulas and any advice would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!